# How to use if_else() on a grouped tibble in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to recalculate an ID based on several conditions in a dataset. The data holds information on the observation year `year`, the customer ID `customer` the ID of the observed plant `plant_code` and whether the observed plant is the main plant `is_main` or a satellite plant `is_satellite`. The main plant is producing output and consumes part of it itself, but for some customers also hands over some of the output to the satellite plant where the rest of the output is consumed.

I would like to assign each satellite plant of a combination of customer and year the ID of the main plant, if there is a main plant. Otherwise, the plant ID should stay unchanged. The newly assigned ID would be named `plant_code_new`.

Here is an example of the data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
 year = c(2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2021, 2022, 2021, 2022, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2021, 2022, 2021, 2022),
 customer = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E"),
 plant_code = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8),
 is_main = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 is_satellite = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I tried to calculate the `plant_code_new` as follows:

```
df_adj <- df |> 
  group_by(year, customer) |> 
  mutate(grp_size = (n() - sum(is_satellite))) |> 
  mutate(plant_code_new = if_else(condition = rep((n() - sum(is_satellite)) == 1, times = n()),
                                  true = plant_code[is_main == 1],
                                  false = plant_code,
                                  size = n()))
```

However I receive the following error message:

> Error in `mutate()`:
> In argument: `plant_code_new = if_else(...)`.
> In group 3: `year = 2021`, `customer = "D"`.
> Caused by error in `if_else()`:
> ! `true` must have size 2, not size 0.

I can't figure out what I am getting wrong here. Why must true have size 2 for customer D in year 2021?
For this combination I would expect that the number of observations in the group is 2 and the number of satellites in the group is also 2. Hence 2- 2 = 0 and the logical test should evaluate to `FALSE`. And return the `plant_code` of each obsveration.

Any advice on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the issue is with `if_else`. Let me demonstrate it with small example.

```
library(dplyr)

if_else(TRUE, 1, 2 + "a")
```

> Error in 2 + "a" : non-numeric argument to binary operator

even if the `TRUE` condition is going to be returned but it still evaluates the `FALSE` condition and returns error because of it.

---

In general, I use `match` instead of `==` because it is more reliable and returns `NA` if the value does not exist. This also solves the issue that you have.

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_by(year, customer) |> 
  mutate(grp_size = (n() - sum(is_satellite))) |> 
  mutate(plant_code_new = if_else(condition = rep((n() - sum(is_satellite)) == 1, times = n()),
                                  true = plant_code[match(1, is_main)],
                                  false = plant_code,
                                  size = n())) 

#    year customer plant_code is_main is_satellite grp_size plant_code_new
#   <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1  2021 A                 1       1            0        1              1
# 2  2021 A                 2       0            1        1              1
# 3  2022 A                 1       1            0        1              1
# 4  2022 A                 2       0            1        1              1
# 5  2021 B                 3       1            0        1              3
# 6  2022 B                 3       1            0        1              3
# 7  2021 C                 4       0            1        0              4
# 8  2022 C                 4       0            1        0              4
# 9  2021 D                 5       0            1        0              5
#10  2021 D                 6       0            1        0              6
#11  2022 D                 5       0            1        0              5
#12  2022 D                 6       0            1        0              6
#13  2021 E                 7       1            0        2              7
#14  2022 E                 7       1            0        2              7
#15  2021 E                 8       1            0        2              8
#16  2022 E                 8       1            0        2              8
```

Or shorter :

```
df |> 
  group_by(year, customer) |> 
  mutate(grp_size = (n() - sum(is_satellite))) |> 
  mutate(plant_code_new = if_else(grp_size == 1,
                                  plant_code[match(1, is_main)],plant_code))
```